If I person come very close to zina (sexchat) but he stops himself is he sinful we
If I person come very close to zina (sexchat) but he stops himself is he sinful

Salam and welcome to islamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Question is unclear. If you performed sex chat then that is sinful, although less sinful than zina. If you were considering doing sex chat but stopped then it is not sinful until you actually do something wrong.

assalamo alaikom "And do not approach unlawful sexual intercourse. Indeed, it is ever an immorality and is evil as a way."
(Qur'an, Surah Al-Isra, 17:32)
The key point here is the wording “do not approach” (in Arabic, la taqrabu). This emphasizes that even coming close to sinful actions (like engaging in sexual conversations) is prohibited.
dont ever come close to these thing the corrupt you soul and heart brother
Keeping yourself busy with halal (permissible) activities to avoid idle time where such temptations may arise.
"And those who, when they commit an immorality or wrong themselves [by sin], remember Allah and seek forgiveness for their sins—and who can forgive sins except Allah?—and [who] do not persist in what they have done while they know."
(Qur'an, Surah Al-Imran, 3:135)
